# how to access and test dom elements in my GWT test case

Tags: java, html, gwt, gwt2

I have a gwt application that heavily relies on html tags present in my host page.

e.g. I have tags such as

```html
<div id="testDiv">
  
  <input type=text id="txt1">
  <input type=button id="submit">
  
</div>
```

then in my GWT component I am binding existing GWT components to these html elements. So e.g. my AddressForm uses the tags laid out in the html to create the actual form.

Now I want to test my AddressForm in unit test using some sample html in host page.

more eg..  I am trying to write a simple AddressBook application by creating the ui based on the html tags present on the host page.

so my typical approach is to

```
Element ele = Document.get().getElementById("addressName") ;
TextBox box = new TextBox(ele) ;
```

so in short I am trying to attach a Gwt widget instance to an appropriate tag present on my html.

I would like to use a custom host html in the test and verify / assert that an appropriate element was found.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: The first thing that pops in mind is, in the unit test, if you can live without the HTML file, and just mock the structure that you need, meaning you can mock the form. It does not need an html page. You can create a FormPanel, or FlowPanel (if you just want a div) and put in any children that you need. Then you need to programmatically fire the onclick handler of a button and make stuff happen. This is just a direction you could try. This might help: http://blog.trifork.com/2008/04/22/test-driven-development-for-gwt-ui-code-with-asynchronous-rpc/

Comment: @JoeyRoosing more than event firing simulation and handling I am keen on understanding how I can test my Dom accessors. I am editing the question to add some more details.